# Matching tags with identical names but different child values

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I am trying to use XMLUnit 2 to compare xml files.

```
<composite>
    <data>
        <subtag>
            <code>1</code>
        </subtag>
        <subtag>
            <code>2</code>
        </subtag>
    </data>
</composite>
```

Second file is the same, with the only difference being 'subtag' tags switched places.

```
<composite>
    <data>
        <subtag>
            <code>2</code>
        </subtag>
        <subtag>
            <code>1</code>
        </subtag>
    </data>
</composite>
```

I've been out of luck so far finding a set of ElementMatchers suitable to match those two as equal.

Is there an out of the box solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much identical to the "`tr` is identified by nested `th`" example from XMLUnit's user-guide. One solution is to use a conditional `ElementSelector` and ensure it uses the correct rule when deciding which `subtag` to take - see https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#conditional-elementselectors

In your concrete case something like

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("subtag")
    .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./code", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

should do. This assumes your `subtag`s are identified by the nested text of their `code` child element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I needed.